# How can I add a subnet that redirects to other subnet on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, redirection

I'm trying to make a new subnet that redirects the connection that it receives to a specific gateway.
I want any request made to 10.1.1.x be redirected to 192.168.1.x
So for example if I ping 10.1.1.23 it should ping 192.168.1.23, or if I make a HTTP request to 10.1.1.25 it should make the request to 192.168.1.25 instead.
Does anyone know if this is possible on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, you can use [NETMAP in iptables](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) (or `dnat` with bitwise operations in nftables).

Comment: @TomYan could you give me an example on how to do it by NETMAP in iptables? thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

For packets originated outside the gateway:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.1.1.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.1.0/24
```

For packets originated on the gateway itself:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.1.1.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.1.0/24
```

(You can do both if need to.)

The manual on this extension is in `man iptables-extensions`, however it is pretty short:

```
   NETMAP
       This target allows you to statically map a whole network of
       addresses onto another network of addresses.  It can only be
       used from rules in the nat table.

       --to address[/mask]
              Network  address  to  map  to.  The resulting address
              will be constructed in the following way: All 'one' 
              bits in the mask are filled in from the new `address'.
              All bits that are zero in the mask are filled in from 
              the original address.

       IPv6 support available since Linux kernels >= 3.7.
```

Notice that this won't persist across reboots. For that you need to use `netfilter-persistent` *and* `iptables-persistent` packages.

Comment: I think it should be added to the `PREROUTING` and/or `OUTPUT` chain (depending on whether it should be applied on traffics from this host or other hosts that use this host as a gateway). `NETMAP` added to `INPUT` and `POSTROUTING` changes the source address instead (i.e. source NAT), I think.

Comment: That's right. Thank you. Of cource, DNAT-type rules go to PREROUTING. Fixed that. However, wouldn't you mind to find out the specific documentation on NETMAP behaviour difference if it's applied into PREROUTING or POSTROUTING chains? Nothing is mentioned in the man page.

Comment: Probably it's not documented anywhere, but as the name `POSTROUTING` implies, the traffics has already been "routed" at that point, which is why you can't add `DNAT` rules to that. And I think the reason you can add `NETMAP` to that is because the chain determines whether the "map" is a source NAT map or destination NAT map. (Actually for inbound traffics, they would already be "routed" when they arrive `INPUT` *or* `FORWARD`.) (In case it wasn't obvious enough, whether you have `-d` and/or `-s` match or neither in your rule doesn't determine what kind of map / NAT it is.)